# Opening hours notification (07:30 tot 22:00) Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display if a store is open or not, on their website. The store is open 7 days a week from 07:30 to 22:00. Now I was able to display it for everyday from 07:00 to 22:00, with the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399628/use-javascript-to-print-out-open-or-closed-depending-on-time-of-day-in-real-ti)([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ApX99/63/)) . But I can't make it start from 07:30, what is the best way to do this?

**Javascript:**

```
var checkOpenStatus = function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var date = d.getHours();
    if ((date > 9) && (date < 20)) {
        y = "<span style=\"color:#07ed11\">We're Open!</span>";
    } else {
        y = "<span style=\"color:#fc4b1c\">Sorry we're Closed.</span>";
    }
    document.getElementById("open-close").innerHTML = y;
};

checkOpenStatus();
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="open-close"></div>
```

Comment: `var minutes = d.getMinutes();`

Comment: var minutes = d.getMinutes(), then use it in your if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the hour is `9` then you also need to check that the minutes are greater than `30`.

```
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();
if ((h > 9 || (h == 9 && m >= 30)) && (h < 20)) {
```

Below is a customised version of the function which injects the date to prove the logic. Run the script and check the console.

```js
var checkOpenStatus = function (d) {
    //var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    if ((h > 9 || (h == 9 && m >= 30)) && (h < 20)) {
        y = "<span style=\"color:#07ed11\">We're Open!</span>";
    } else {
        y = "<span style=\"color:#fc4b1c\">Sorry we're Closed.</span>";
    }
    console.log(d, y);
};

checkOpenStatus(new Date(2017, 1, 1, 9, 0));
checkOpenStatus(new Date(2017, 1, 1, 9, 10));
checkOpenStatus(new Date(2017, 1, 1, 9, 20));
checkOpenStatus(new Date(2017, 1, 1, 9, 30));
checkOpenStatus(new Date(2017, 1, 1, 9, 40));
checkOpenStatus(new Date(2017, 1, 1, 10, 40));
checkOpenStatus(new Date(2017, 1, 1, 20, 00));
checkOpenStatus(new Date(2017, 1, 1, 23, 00));
```